# How to increase the prediction accuracy of CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on training a model for plant disease classification. I got 90% validation accuracy [image]

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE, activation='relu',))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE, activation='relu',))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE, activation='relu',))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE, activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())


model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

I tested the model using a separate unseen dataset. The below matrix shows the result I got with the unseen dataset. When I choose random images from that dataset, sometimes none of them is predicted correctly, although the matrix shows that it has been classified correctly. Please help me to solve this. I am a newbie. To get an idea, please refer to the disease "target spot."It is predicted as "Two spider Mites two-spotted spider Mites" although in the matrix it is not predicted like that
[image: Confusion Matrix]
[image: Prediction]

Comment: I would suggest you include some more details, like the architecture of the net you are using and your accuracy and loss curves.

Comment: Thanx I will add them

Answer (score 1):

Your model clearly shows that it is over fitting. Over fitting means that model is working fine on training dataset but it is not working good on validation and test dataset. So there are many techniques to remove the over fitting of model. I am mentioning some of them here

1. Increase the complexity of model. Your model has only four convolution layers and one dense layer. So increase the both layers especially convolution layers.
2. Hyperparameter tuning

   a). Which optimizer you are using. Try to use the Adam optimizer it works good most of
   time.

   b) Try to use learning rate scheduler after some epochs change the learning rate using
   scheduler it will decrease the loss and increase accuracy.

   c) Weight decay. Use weight decay in optimizer. It improves overfitting problem.

   d) Try to use different batch size

3. Increase your dataset. If you dont have more dataset you can use the augmentation technique (in Keras it is datagenerator) to increase the dataset.

Try with all these parameters and don't loose hope you will do it. It needs patience and trying again and again.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, Imran for your answer it will help me.                                                             
I have used the learning rate of 0.001. Is it ok to reduce this more? I have used the adam in the compilation

Comment: You are welcome.
First make your model more complex  like add layers. This learning rate is good for start. Run your model for more number of epochs. Like for 100 to 500. Increase the dataset in such a way like first just start with flipping horizontally 50 % of images (randomly) and it will increase 50% data

Comment: oh, thnx ok I will. I have used only 10 epochs with 27 batch size

Comment: If you like it you can accept the answer by clicking it.